# How to Read Images from storage in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Can anyone show me how to read images .png or .jpg from .cn1 (Stoarge) in codenameOne.

i tried two ways they both don t work :

1-  img = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("img.png"));

2-  img = Image.createImage(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("img.png"));

the errors i get are **respectively**:

1- Warning: loading large images using EncodedImage.create(InputStream) might lead to memory issues, try using EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int)

--> When i try **EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int size)** and i execute the function: "**findImageViewer().setImage(img);**" , i get :
**java.lang.NullPointerException**

2) with "findImageViewerRdM().setImage(img);" i get java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You need to provide the stack trace of the exception. My guess is that findImageViewer() returns null because you invoked it before the form is shown. You should use findImageViewer(f) in the before show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me so please check it .

```
InputStream is =  Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("tizbn.JPG");

        EncodedImage i = EncodedImage.create(is, is.available());
        ImageViewer imageViewer = new ImageViewer(i);
        f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, imageViewer);
```

Comment: I guess something went wrong with my installation of CN1 on Eclipse because even most basic thing won't function like:                                     Image i = Image.createImage("/sil5.png");     
findImageViewerRdM().setImage(i);

Comment: i will try to reinstall it and see. but thank you sir for the answers !

Comment: the images can be read and displayed now, the problem was related to the findImageViewer...

Answer (score 2):

img = EncodedImage.create(Storage.getInstance().createInputStream("img.png", int )); 
Please use the next method with int variable one
create(InputStream i, int size) of EncodedImage

Comment: I do try it as well but as i described in my question i get a null pointer when i try to display it on an imageviewer.